# How to pass the value from url of php to .js

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I am new to javascript and I am trying to pass a value from Get in url of php to javascript.
This is my code.

this is the url

```
someproject/index.php?roomId=2
```

index.php

room = $_GET['roomId'];

```
<input hidden id="room" value=<?=$room;?>>
```

script.js

I want to get the value from php and I want something like:

```
$('#room').getValueFromPHP();
```

but I do not know how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: You are already there. Did you already tried something? Like $("#room").val();

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

PHP

```
<input type="hidden" id="room" value="<?=$room;?>">
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {// make sure the document is ready.
    var url = $("#room").val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a value from PHP to JavaScript, you can use echo as follows:

```
<?php $room = $_GET['roomId']; ?>

<script> var room = <?php echo "'$room'"; ?>; </script>
```